# How to select the cross streets in postgis spatial table?

Tags: postgis, spatial-database, postgis-2.0

I've used ST_Intersects and ST_Crosses but between two different tables. 
I have a table of streets and intersections want to know them. 
For example select all streets that cross the Street A. 
Can anyone give me an example?

Edited for karpfen**

This is my table of streets, each street segment is a geometry table. 
The image of the QGIS layer can better understand, analyze and think it would be appropriate to use ST_Touches and select geometry that touches the other at its end. 
But how do it in the same table?? I can not do a join.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  b.*
FROM table1 AS a, 
 (SELECT * from table1) AS b 
WHERE ST_Crosses(a.way, b.way)
```

Comment: You know how to do this in Oracle SQL I tried and the error [Err] ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform a spatial join on the two tables. Try something like

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON (st_crosses(table1.geometry,table2.geometry))
```

EDIT:

As the solution above only applies to geometries in multiple tables, here is another one:

You can use PostGIS topology tables and have all intersections stored as nodes in it. [Here](http://blog.mathieu-leplatre.info/use-postgis-topologies-to-clean-up-road-networks.html) is a good tutorial for that (the tutorial aims at cleaning up road networks, but it'll serve your purpose as well though).

Comment: Sorry, I may not have been clear in my question. 
But I have only one table is a table of streets and wonder intersections of streets. I edited the question.